# is there a way to automatically set UITextfield delegate from interface builder?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

When adding a UITextfield to a controller in interface builder, is there any way to have the text field's delegate property automatically set to the controller that you placed the UITextfield on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the way how to set it automatically:

Override textfield's *awakeFromNib* method, get it's viewController, check protocol conformity and set textField delegate to this vc.

```
extension UITextField {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let vc = self.getViewController() as? UITextFieldDelegate {
            self.delegate = vc
        }
    }
}
```

Here is UIView's extension to find parent viewController via responder chain:

```
extension UIView {
    func getViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return (self.next as? UIViewController) ?? (self.next as? UIView)?.getViewController()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select the TextField, hold down the Control key and drag the line to the ViewController, release and select the delegate.